# Typedef Circular Dependency

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, circular-dependency

How can I solve the following circular dependency?

```
typedef boost::variant<int, bool, double, std::string, Structure> Value;
typedef std::list<std::pair<std::string, ValueContainer>> Structure;
typedef std::vector<Value> ValueContainer;
```

I'm attempting to represent objects from a C api database library in a more C++ form. This database allows one to store values or arrays of values, as well as having a representation for Structures, as follows:

```
typedef struct ApiStructureMember 
{
    char* name;
    struct ApiValueContainer value;
    struct ApiStructureMember_T* next;
} ApiStructureMember_T;
```

Finally, a union is used to represent a value, as follows:

```
typedef struct ApiValue 
{
    union 
    {
        int i;
        const char*   s;
        ...
        struct ApiStructureMember_T* firstStructureMember;
    } value;
} ApiValue_T;
```

Comment: Can you describe what more general problem you're trying to solve with this scheme? Or clarify if you intend this more as a pedantic exercise?

Comment: [`make_recursive_variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.recursive.recursive-variant) should help, somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have types **mutually containing** each other. Think about it: the compiler would get into an infinite loop generating the data.

There are two general patterns: the first is through **data types pointing to each other**

```
struct OddNode; // forward declaration

struct EvenNode 
{
    OddNode* prev;
    OddNode* next;
};

struct OddNode
{
    EvenNode* prev;
    EvenNode* next;
};
```

If you leave away the pointers, and implement the Even and Odd nodes with containment by value, then the compiler can never resolve the definitions.

In general: just draw a picture of how you want to lay out the data, with boxes representing data and lines connecting the various parts. Then replace each box with a class, and each line with a pointer to the corresponding class. If you have a circular dependency somewhere, simply forward declare the classes at the top of your code.

The second circular dependency is through the **Curiously Recurring Template Parameter** (CRTP)

```
template<typename T> 
struct Y 
{};

struct X
: 
    public Y<X> 
{};
```

Your example would be using the CRTP with `Structure` as `X` and `std::list< ..., Structure>` as `Y<X>`.

Comment: The types don't, strictly speaking, contain each other, one contains a vector of the other, but the actual data will be dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this a solution?

```
class Structure;
typedef boost::variant<int, bool, double, std::string, Structure> Value;
typedef std::vector<Value> ValueContainer;

class Structure: public std::list<std::pair<std::string, ValueContainer>>
{
};
```

Comment: Yes, it is, I updated my answer. It's part of a subtle template pattern.